# How to pass the requested path to the index.php file without last slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using following code

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But i dont what to send last optimal slash (`/`) to the $1 parameter.

For example i neet to:

```
http://domain.com/a/b/c/subject
  OR
http://domain.com/a/b/c/subject/
  Rewrite to
http://domain.com/index.php?q=$1
```

And i tried to use `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make last slash optional, use `+` quantifier and add a condition to avoid looping:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What is the mean of first question sign?

Comment: `.+?` is a non-greedy regex use for capturing text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

This code works for me every time :)